# Apache redirection of host:port/dir to anotherhost:port/dir

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to redirect some requests to another server. Every request to http://host:port/dir should be redirected to http://anotherhost:port/dir.
I already tried using ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse, RewriteCond/RewriteRule, etc., but nothing worked out.

Can someone help me please?
Thank you in advance

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The first thing to do is listen to the port, ie: if for instance what we are trying to do is redirect to http://anotherhost:8080/dir every request from http://host:8080/dir, we should listen to port 8080, so, the next line must be in httpd.conf.

```
Listen 8080
```

Then, we need to configure the proxy:

```
ProxyRequests On

ProxyPass /dir http://anotherhost:8080/dir
ProxyPassReverse /dir http://anotherhost:8080/dir
```

I hope this could help someone

Greetings